# What does the difference of the JNI method CallObjectMethod,CallObjectMethodV and CallObjectMethodA?

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

There are 3 kinds of methods in JNI
CallObjectMethod
CallObjectMethodV
CallObjectMethodA
So what does the difference of the methods?

```
jobject     (*CallObjectMethod)(JNIEnv*, jobject, jmethodID, ...);
jobject     (*CallObjectMethodV)(JNIEnv*, jobject, jmethodID, va_list);
jobject     (*CallObjectMethodA)(JNIEnv*, jobject, jmethodID, jvalue*);
```

Comment: Did you, at least, try looking for [JNI documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#wp16656)?

Answer (score 6):

The only difference is the way how java arguments are passed. [Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#wp16656) explain all it very well:

> **Call<type>Method Routines**
>
> Programmers place all arguments that are to
>   be passed to the method immediately following the methodID argument.
>   The CallMethod routine accepts these arguments and passes them
>   to the Java method that the programmer wishes to invoke.
>
> **Call<type>MethodA Routines**
>
> Programmers place all arguments to the
>   method in an args array of jvalues that immediately follows the
>   methodID argument. The CallMethodA routine accepts the arguments
>   in this array, and, in turn, passes them to the Java method that the
>   programmer wishes to invoke.
>
> **Call<type>MethodV Routines**
>
> Programmers place all arguments to the
>   method in an args argument of type va_list that immediately follows
>   the methodID argument. The CallMethodV routine accepts the
>   arguments, and, in turn, passes them to the Java method that the
>   programmer wishes to invoke.

Comment: what to pass if Java function does not need any parameter?

Comment: @AnuranBarman just use the `Method` without additional parameters after the methodID.